# Android Preview vs Emulator Layout Size

Tags: android, android-studio

Folks,

I cant design my android screens and see it on my emulator somehow the resolution, zoom (whatever) in the emulator is big and my layout is messed up.

The whole layout is inside a FrameLayout, the paragraph text in the emulator pic is inside a RelativeLayout, which is set to GONE after users upload rating, then LinearLayout shows up with the overall rating bar in the some place where the RelativeLayout was.

My question is why is this happening since in the preview it seems perfect and on the emulator it seems all messed.

Please see the screenshots:

Android Studio Preview:
[image: Everything fits]

Genymotion Emulator
[image: The first rating bar shows up after users submits rating, on preview it fits the screen nicely]

Comment: Please mark on the photo.

Comment: sorry I didnt understand your request @tinysunlight

Comment: Please add your layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to determine what exactly is wrong without seeing your xml markup.

**Possible Reasons**

1. You gave your layouts some sort of fixed size, and therefore it appears to be fine on your markup, but whatever you are emulating on Genymotion is using a different ratio.
2. When you do a View.GONE, you say you are replacing a RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout. Well, do you make sure that the layout that is replaced is layoutAbove whatever that frame layout below it is?
3. Some layout just has some attribute, like an alignment issue, that is causing this.

Trace your steps backwards, removing one thing at a time. Get it to work with that view gone first, then add it and manipulate it after.